# Converting an Elixir number in exponent notation to integer

Tags: elixir

How do I convert an Elixir exponent to an integer?

I'd like to convert something like `1.0e2` to `100`.
I've googled around for a solution but haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Turns out you can use `trunc(number)` and it will convert a number in exponent notation to an integer.

`trunc(1.0e2) => 100`

Note - this doesn't work for floats, as it will truncate the decimal.

Comment: `1.0e2` is a float. `100` is an integer. Are you trying to convert from float to int?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you call *exponent* is really just a floating point number written in [*scientific notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), sometimes also called *exponential notation*. The actual *exponent* is actually just a part of this whole thing. Together with the *mantissa* it allows us to conveniently represent very large and/or small numbers:

```
mantissa * (10 ^ exponent)
```

So in Elixir, as in many other languages, the number `1.23 * (10 ^ 5)` can be written as `1.23e5`. If you type your example number `1.0e2` into `iex`, you will see that it is really just a convenience on top of floating point numbers:

```
iex> 1.0e2
100.0
```

So the question should really be: "How do I convert a float to an integer?". The answer to this is that you can use one of the following functions to achieve this:

- `Kernel.round/1` – round
- `Kernel.trunc/1` – drop digits after decimal point
- `Float.round/2` – round with precision
- `Float.floor/2` – round up with precision
- `Float.ceil/2` – round down with precision

The `Kernel` functions are [allowed in guard tests](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#expressions-in-guard-clauses), and you don't need to put the `Kernel.` in front in order to call them. The `Float` functions additionally allow you to specify a precision in order to preserve some digits after the decimal point. With your example it doesn't really matter which one you use, because `100.0` is a whole number. The behavior of the functions mentioned above is however best illustrated with a different number, say `1.55`:

```
iex> round(1.55)
2

iex> trunc(1.55)
1

iex> Float.round(1.55)
2.0

iex> Float.round(1.55, 1)
1.6

iex> Float.floor(1.55)
1.0

iex> Float.floor(1.55, 1)
1.5

iex> Float.ceil(1.55)
2.0

iex> Float.ceil(1.55, 1)
1.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response!